# How can I fill a circle in libgdx?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, geometry, shape-rendering

using the [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html) class, I can only fill rectangles.

- So how can I fill a circle?
- and if possible, fill a sector (portion of a circle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the example of the shaperender

```
 shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
 shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
 shapeRenderer.rect(x, y, width, height); // fills a rect
 shapeRenderer.circle(x, y, radius);//<--- fills a circle
 shapeRenderer.end();
```

should fill the circle. How to get a portion of a cicle i have no clue. Maybe create a mesh and fill it or such like that. Take a look at the shaperender there are differnet methods to fill parts. Just check if some of them fit.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, there is a method that fills only a portion of a circle

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
shapeRenderer.arc(x, y, radius, start, degrees, segments); // Fills a portion of a circle
shapeRenderer.end();
```